# Assigning external JSON to a var

Tags: javascript, json, dojo, assign

I am populating a Dojo Combobox dropdown with values from JSON.
The code below works just fine (inline JSON).....

```
<script>
var magicvars = {
   identifier: 'name',
   label: 'name',
   items: [
   {name: "ZCCN_NO_1", label: "<img width='16px' height='16px' src='http://localhost:3000/static/images/eight_ball_16x16.png'/>ACCN_NO_1"},
   {name: "CR_Local_ID", label:"<img width='16px' height='16px' src='http://localhost:3000/static/images/eight_ball_16x16.png'/>CR_Local_ID"}
]};
</script>

<div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" data="magicvars" jsId="xvarStore2"></div>
```

However when I specify an external file for the JSON, no go, which is to say that the dropdown populates.
The external file is standard.txt and looks like this...

```
{
  identifier: 'name',
  label: 'name',
  items: [
  {name: "ZCCN_NO_1", label: "<img width='16px' height='16px' src='http://localhost:3000/static/images/eight_ball_16x16.png'/>ACCN_NO_1"},
  {name: "CR_Local_ID", label:"<img width='16px' height='16px' src='http://localhost:3000/static/images/eight_ball_16x16.png'/>CR_Local_ID"}
 ]};
```

My HTML call to dojo the looks like this..

```
<div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" jsId="xvarStore2" url="http://localhost:3000/static/standard.txt">
</div>
```

Inline works fine but the external call does not. Apologies if this is a remedial question but how can I read the external file and assign it to "magicvars". I just don't want to clutter up the HTML with a bunch of inline JSON.

Any advice is appreciated.
Janie

Comment: please see the comments in the answer below.  The ending semicolon in your JSON file is what's giving you the error, not the unquoted property names.  Of course, proper JSON should be quoted -- and there is an internal discussion/debate within Dojo whether to convert xhr calls to use JSON.parse instead -- so unquoted property names may no longer work in version 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not valid JSON, so will not parse with most `JSON.parse` implementations.  Try quoting the key names and getting rid of the trailing semicolon.

On Chrome,

```
JSON.parse('{ a: "b" }')
```

produces

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

as does

```
JSON.parse('{ a: "b" };')
```

but with valid JSON (note the quotes around `"a"`)

```
JSON.parse('{ "a": "b" }')
```

returns the expected result.

Comment: BAM! That is the answer! Mike you're the best, thank you so much! J.W.

Comment: This is strange, as ItemFileReadStore uses `dojo.xhrGet` to get the URL content, and then passes it to `dojo.fromJson` to parse.  `dojo.fromJson` actually does an `eval` and not `JSON.parse`.  So the properties without quotes should also work...  Never tried it though.

Comment: @Stephen, In `{ a: foo }` the `a` is a label just as in `{ a: for (...) { ... break a; } }`.  So `dojo.fromJson` probably wraps the input in parentheses to force `eval` to treat it as an expression.  `({ a: foo };)` is neither a valid statement nor a valid expression because of the semicolon.  Some JSON parsers that use `eval` also do a bunch of regexp tricks to prevent XSS via JSON.  Those may also have caused the error.

Comment: that's a good observation.  dojo.fromJson does wrap the input in parentheses.  So it is the semicolon -- I overlooked it.  But in that case, JSON.parse will not work right even if the property names are quoted, and neither will dojo.fromJson.  The OP probably got rid of the semicolon after putting in the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your file to `standard.json`.

My guess is that dojo is reading your file as a plain text string, and therefor not parsing the JSON.  (Which, as pointed out in other answers, is *not* valid)

Comment: Nope.  ItemFileReadStore uses `dojo.xhrGet` to get the URL, which defaults to the type "json-comment-optional".  The text is *always* parsed as JSON.